# Docker on EC2 failing to connect to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I wanted to improve the security of my deployment regarding storing secrets keys in a safe place.

So I followed this tutorial : [How to Manage Secrets for Amazon EC2 Container Service–Based Applications by Using Amazon S3 and Docker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-manage-secrets-for-amazon-ec2-container-service-based-applications-by-using-amazon-s3-and-docker/)
But without the CloudWatch template (I already have a VPC, a Cluster and other instances)
I am using my own project (A Flask application that works fine with the secrets in the task definition)

I set up the S3 bucket, the VPC endpoint, everything works fine.
But when my docker container launches, I got an error:

```
download failed: s3://[my-bucket]/[my-secrets].txt to - An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Which basically occurs when the entrypoint script run the command

```
aws s3 cp s3://${SECRETS_BUCKET_NAME}/secrets.txt -
```

Note : I defined SECRETS_BUCKET_NAME in the task definitions, as well as other variables that does not need to be secret.

First I thought that my instance did not have correct roles, so for debug purposes I attached it AdministratorAccess policy, but without success.

Secondly I read that Docker containers shares the credentials of the host (the EC2 instance), so I directly installed on the instance the aws-cli bundle and set the credentials for a user who has AdministratorAccess policy.

Now I can run manually when logged in on my instance the command

```
aws s3 cp s3://${SECRETS_BUCKET_NAME}/secrets.txt -
```

And it works fine, but my container still gets the 403 error.

My EC2 instance is an amzn-ami-2017.03.c-amazon-ecs-optimized image (which weirdly, does not include the aws-cli)

If anybody has an idea of what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Attach to your running container and run `env`, see if the `SECRETS_BUCKET_NAME` is defined inside the container or not?

Comment: `SECRET_BUCKET_NAME` is defined, I have a check before running the command. `docker inspect [container]` shows that it is there too.

Comment: Use `docker run --net=host` for your container and see if then it works?

Comment: Same error. Although I dont get your point, the problem is that the roles of my instance seems not to apply.

Comment: Test the statement on your docker host machine and then question whether it work inside docker. If doesn't work on Host no point digging docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I updated the AMI to a more recent one, remade the proper roles and it worked.

I noticed a weird thing tho: The ECS Optimized Amazon's AMI do not include the aws-cli.

Answer (score 0):

There is another potential issue which may causes an access deny for AWS CLI when run in a container while running directly on host works perfectly.

If you switch to IMDS v2 and set a policy to deny operations with IMDS v1 credentials it may block all AWS CLI calls because:

- the default ECS Launch Configuration settings have instance-metadata-options' w http-put-response-hop-limit set to 1,
- docker introduces an extra layer for network connections and thus it takes 2 hops to reach metadata,
- as result AWS CLI cannot get a token from metadata and therefor switches to IMDS v1 which is then blocked by the policy mentioned above.

The solution is to set http-put-response-hop-limit to 2.